# How to call the default Register method from javascript? in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In a classic `ASP.Net` `MVC` project i want to move the register link feature to a button instead. (so what ever happens on register click will happen on a button click). Simple enough! I did the following.

**Login.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-8  col-md-push-1">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <input type="button" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="register();"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**added a script to the same page**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function register() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Register", "Account")",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success');
            },
            type: 'GET'
        });
    }
</script>
```

Now the Register function in Account Controller has two overloads

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    return View();
}

public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var geUser  = new User { Password = model.Password, Username = model.Email, AccessLevel = "0003", LoggedIn = false, Active = true, AllowOffline = false, LastSettingsRefreshed = DateTime.Now };

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email,  user = geUser};
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Send an email with this link
            // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

So now I want to call the second function instead of the first one...

- how do i pass the RegisterViewModel from javascript? OR
- As currently i am calling the function that has no parameters, can i change it so that it redirects to the register page?

**RegisterViewModel**

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]        
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Start by changing it to `type: 'GET'`. But you have not shown the relevant part of the view for `RegisterViewModel` so its impossible to tell how to send the data associated with that model.

Comment: And `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` in you POST method is pointless - its and ajax call and ajax calls never redirect. Why would you want to make an ajax call instead of a normal submit, and why do you have both Login and Register forms in the same bview?

Comment: Hi Stephen. I have added RegisterViewModel

Comment: No, I do not mean the model. I meant the form controls in the view you have shown. But its difficult to understand what your wanting to do. Do you want to just redirect to the `Register()` method so you display the Register view (in which case you use a link and style it to look like a button if that is what you want), or are you wanting to post the Register POST method?

Comment: yes i just want to show the registerviewmodel when register button is clicked!

Comment: From you image, it looks like you view is for the Login form, and you just want to redirect, in which case its the first case in my previous comment - i.e. style the link to look like a button

Comment: the mainNav navbar on_Layout.cshtml is not displayed at all (display:none) so this login snapshot is the only thing we see on the first page

Comment: okay if add it as a link instead of button and then it works fine <ul><li class="page-scroll">@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account")</li></ul>

Comment: And if you want it to look like your button, then its `@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })`

Comment: ok did that thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So i have simply used an action link instead of the button and as suggested by Stephen Muecke made it look like a button control